# Was ist Bewerberbogen auf Englisch?

Tags: vocabulary

I habe eine E-mail bekommen und es gibt das wort "Bewerberbogen". Was ist das auf English?

Vielen Dank,

Víctor

Comment: Which sources did you consult so far? http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/bewerberbogen.html is among the first Google hits for "Bewerberbogen Englisch" and already gives some good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich würde es mit "application sheet" übersetzen. Da es offenbar kein "Bewerbungsbogen" (= "application form") ist, handelt es sich hierbei um ein Formular, das von einem Bewerber auszufüllen ist, damit das Unternehmen seine Daten erfassen kann.

Oder ist eine englische Erklärung gewünscht?